# Get currently viewed text in window using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've had this random idea for a JavaScript function which returns the text the user is currently observing/rendered/basically reading. I thought this would be impossible (or very difficult) due to the content which being read is often contained in divisions which extend beyond the window into the document.

I thought it may be possible to get the current scroll position, then move down the window height to grab all the divs in that area. But, if it simply selected everything viewed - that would include content out of perspective.

```js
function reading() {
  let locationOfWindow = $(window).offset();
  // use to gather text data
}
```

**Edit** the idea of wrapping every single word with a span for the important bits wished to be viewed, then cycling through every single one of these classed-spans to check if it's on-screen to create a cache then re-put together, but seems inefficient and only if no other ideas exist.

**Note** I do not mean "get every element that can be viewed" but instead "get every bit of text that can be viewed" in **window** at the time - if you're scrolled half-way through a large paragraph on a screen, you're missing half of the actual content in window.

Comment: There's a [jQuery plugin for that](https://benpickles.github.io/onScreen/)

Comment: @Moob Thanks for the contribution :~) - I understand the ability to tell if an element is on the screen, but I am looking for just one layer deeper than that but to get the text nodes specifically. As I write this, would it be a possible hack to wrap every word in a span to check if being observed using this plugin too? Jesus, that sounds like a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment. There's a simple [plugin by Ben Pickles](https://benpickles.github.io/onScreen/) that will tell you if the element is in the viewport. From there it's a simple matter of just getting the text from the element.

Here's a proof of concept to get you started. Scroll the viewport. The text of the in-view elements will be logged to the console.

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
      console.clear();
    $("*:visible:onScreen").each(function() {
      console.log($(this).prop('nodeName'),$(this).text());
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // onScreen jQuery plugin v0.2.1
  // (c) 2011-2013 Ben Pickles
  //
  // http://benpickles.github.io/onScreen
  //
  // Released under MIT license.
  (function(a) {
    a.expr[":"].onScreen = function(b) {
      var c = a(window),
        d = c.scrollTop(),
        e = c.height(),
        f = d + e,
        g = a(b),
        h = g.offset().top,
        i = g.height(),
        j = h + i;
      return h >= d && h < f || j > d && j <= f || i > e && h <= d && j >= f
    }
  })(jQuery);
</script>


<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem. Sit amet risus nullam eget. Eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus
  vestibulum. Enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat. Nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus. A diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget. Purus non enim praesent
  elementum facilisis. Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat nam. Integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu. Neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec. Dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra.
</p>
<div>
  Amet dictum sit amet justo donec enim. Adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in. In ante metus dictum at tempor. Est velit egestas dui id ornare. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Ligula ullamcorper
  malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit. Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu. Donec
  et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. Tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi. Cras fermentum odio
  eu feugiat pretium nibh. Non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo.
</div>
<section>
  Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi. Non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Nisl tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis. Dictum non consectetur
  a erat nam at. A lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio. Eu consequat ac felis donec et. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus. Maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Congue
  eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam. Laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu. Egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere. Amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu
  felis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel.
</section>
<blockquote>
  Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet. Neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero.
  In hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi. Luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut
  consequat semper viverra. Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Purus in massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id. Odio aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique.
  Nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper. Nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum.
</blockquote>
<pre>
Consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi. Enim sed faucibus turpis in. Iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra. Sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget. At risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque. Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget velit. At tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non. Neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit. Ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing. Mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales. Vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit.</pre>
```

Comment: As I said in my responding comment, this is a very good general grabber for the entire dividers that contain text that might peek the viewport. The problem is, the idea is for the exact set of words that are viewable to the user in **window**. Your code displays the entire block the second it comes into partial view or shows words that aren't viewable at that time (needs more scrolling) - the practice of this is for algorithmic purposes (why I am being so strict).